# Python Seaborn heatmap annotations after masking

Tags: python, plot, visualization, heatmap, seaborn

I am creating a Seaborn heatmap with a given pandas dataframe that has numbers and nan's. Something like so:

```
1 2 nan
4 nan nan
nan nan nan
```

I need the heatmap to be annoted and I also need to mask/grey out all the nans. I found the mask function and can use it like so:

```
mask = df.isnull()
```

Then, I can create the heatmap like so:

```
sns.heatmap(df, mask = mask, annot = True, fmt = "g", cmap = "Blues")
```

The problem is, with the mask, it seems the nan's are transformed into strings while the numbers stay as floats. I get the following exception:

> ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'

With something like this happening (partial plot before it throws the exception):

[image]

As you can tell, the first cell formatted is fine as it's a float, but then, when it gets to the nan that is masked, it seems it is not a string and cannot be formatted.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to annotate only the unmasked data?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't say what version of seaborn you are using but I think this has been fixed: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/497

Comment: I have seaborn==0.5.1

It should be the latest.

Comment: It seems a simple pip install will not give me the latest version. I forked the latest dev version from Github.